# Simple models with non-abelian anyons

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, topological-phase, anyons

It is well known, that in 1d and 2d there are particles with anyone statistics.

Which 1d and 2d models have such excitations? Which model with anyons is simplest?

Comment: What criterion are you using for "simple"? The fractional quantum Hall states are obtained by considering electrons with Coulomb interactions in two-dimensions in a perpendicular magnetic field. Such states have been realized experimentally for almost 4 decades (though showing experimentally that the particles are non-abelian anyons is very hard).

Comment: Take a look at the Fractional quantum Hall effect, and Chern-Simons theory.